# OS: Parrot Security 6.0 (lorikeet) x8 Automatically end current session

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bug

When I open a file which name is " Shiva Svarodaya with Hindi Translation 1899 - Khemraj Shri Krishna Das.pdf  " when open with atril document viewer SUddenly I automatically  It ends the current session

And one more thing is when I open firefox-esr and try to download chrome from its official website and when I click on Accept and download at this time Automatically it end the current session then I have login again all the time this is

also, sometime its happen when I using cmd

Comment: Are you using Firefox or Chrome? You should [edit] your question to specify what version of Firefox you’re using precisely. I can’t tell if your problem is with the PDF or your inability to download Chrome.

Comment: Please ask only a single question per post. Please explain further what you mean when you say " it ends the current session". Do you mean this action signs you out of the computer, or does it close an application (which one?), or something else? Also, does the same behavior happen if you open a different PDF file, or if you use a different document viewer application? Please EDIT your question to add this information and make it more clear.